# Pass parameter from View to controller MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass selected value of dropdownlist from view to controller in html.BeginForm in MVC 4.

I can pass value of query string, but I have no idea about how to pass selected value of dropdownlist.
All suggestions are most welcome.
Here is my code attached

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="form-group" id="ddl2">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Section Type:</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("ddlsection")
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .OptionLabel("--Select--")
                .DataSource(source =>
                 {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetSectionType", "LookUp");
                    });
                })
                .Events(e => e.Change("onChange_ddlsection"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
            )
    </fieldset>
</form>
    <div class="WordClass">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("GetConditionListingInWord", "Inspection", new { sectionId = 'What should be here?' }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value=""  class="WordClassA tooltipSource" title='Print List in MS-Word format'  data-placement='bottom' data-toggle='tooltip' />
        }
    </div>
```

I want 'ddlsection' dropdown's selected value in 'What should be here?' section.

Comment: For a start, your `Kendo().DropDownList()` needs to be inside the form tags. Not sure what you mean by `new { sectionId = 'What should be here?' }`? Is `sectionId` the value you want to bind to?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. yes, sectionId is the perameter name and I want to bind selected value of dropdown with this.

Comment: Remove `new { sectionId = 'What should be here?' }` and put your dropdownlist inside the `<form>` tags and name it `sectionId`

Comment: I have to pass value of 7 dropdownlist and 2 text fields in controller. Thought I have to put all of these inside <form> tag?

Comment: If you want to post the values to your controller method, then yes (but use a model, not 9 parameters in your POST method)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke : Thanks bro... I just put my dropdowns and textfields inside form. And I got all the dropdowns in controller. Now it works for me.

Comment: why you are using 2 forms ?

Comment: I just removed two forms and included all the controls in Html.BeginForm

Answer (score -1):

You can pass Kendo Dropdownlist's selected value to the Controller using Ajax call and then redirect to another Action if you want as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
    $(function () {
 
        //Returns Dropdownlist's selected values to the Controller
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
 
            var data = {
                ProjectID: $('#ProjectID').val(), //parameter I
                IssueID: $('#IssueID').val()      //parameter II
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/Action",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: this.dataType,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                 
                success: function (data) {
                    // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
                    window.location = "/Controller/OtherAction/" + data
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $("#error_message").html(data);
                }
            }); 
        });

    });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
For that you have to make AJAX call to your controler method

var userModel = {
             RoleId: $("#drpRoleId").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        }

$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddEditUser","User")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(userModel),
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
           }
});
```